# Page numbers and address formatting in letters in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

I've recently turned away from the `letter` document class for writing my covering letters as I'd like a little more creative freedom with the formatting, and as my own little exercise in formatting LaTeX. I'm almost done with my template, but I just have two teeny questions.

1. Is there a way to suppress page numbers for a single paged document, but allow them if my letter spills over to a second page (without compiling and checking manually)? And also,
2. Is there a way to align the rightmost point of the return address at the top with the rightmost part of the main body? I'd normally do it manually after compiling, but since I like to put the date in there, the length keeps changing. If that's a little vague, here's an MWE (using tabular, which is as close as I've gotten):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \hfill\begin{tabular}{l}
   a) Return address\\
   b) Here's a short line\\
   c) Here's a slightly longer line
   \end{tabular}\\
   \end{minipage}\
   \noindent Here's a really long bit of text, to show where the line breaks are normally, and to show that at the moment, they don't line up. The end of the line labelled c) should align with the line breaks in this body of texts, and the start of line a) and b) should align with the start of line c).

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: There are a multitude of document classes for letter; e.g. koma-script. No need to roll your own.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Since your document seems fairly simple (doesn't contain floating environments like `figure`s or `table`s), you can use the [`lastpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) to pick up the value of the last page within your document. [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) is another package which provides the means to translate references (including a page reference) into a counter, so one can examine the value or condition on it.

   Specifically, I would use the following in your document preamble:

   ```
   \usepackage{lastpage,refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lastpage,refcount}
   \newcounter{lastpage}
   \AtBeginDocument{%
     \setcounterpageref{lastpage}{LastPage}%
     \ifnum\value{lastpage}=1\thispagestyle{empty}\fi%
   }
   ```

   The `lastpage` package defines the *page* reference `LastPage`. This is extracted using `refcount`'s `\setcounterpageref` and stored in a newly-created counter `lastpage`. Then, `\AtBeginDocument` we check whether the value of `lastpage` is 1 and set the page style accordingly. The default page style is otherwise used (`plain` in this case).

   We need to set and check `lastpage` `\AtBeginDocument`, since the `.aux` file with the `LastPage` reference is only read at the end of the preamble, leaving `LastPage` undefined until then.

   Using this approach requires you to compile your document at least *twice*. The first time to write the correct page reference to the `.aux` file, and the second time to read the update value from it.
2. A `tabular` necessarily inserts some spacing around its columns. This is given by the length `\tabcolsep` (`6pt` in [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls), and may be different in other document classes). You can override the right-hand column separation by using the column specification `l@{}`.

   Specifically your `tabular` definition might look like this:

   ```
   \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
   %...
   \end{tabular}
   ```

The following minimal example highlights the above two points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lastpage,refcount}
\newcounter{lastpage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounterpageref{lastpage}{LastPage}%
  \ifnum\value{lastpage}=1\thispagestyle{empty}\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\null\hfill\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
a) Return address\\
b) Here's a short line\\
c) Here's a slightly longer line
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

In the above example, use `\lipsum[1-9]` to see the effect of the page style change. Remember to compile *twice*.

The [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) merely provides dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.